# Handling Accept encoding in esb mule

Tags: api, http-headers, mule, gzip, esb

I have mule flow look like below

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns:metadata="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/metadata" xmlns:scripting="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting" xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting/current/mule-scripting.xsd">
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8111" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
    <http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration"  host="api.bonanza.com" port="443" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration" protocol="HTTPS"/>
    <flow name="bonanza_fetchtoken_ceFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/add" allowedMethods="GET,POST" doc:name="HTTP" />
        <flow-ref name="bonanza_addfixedpriceitemSub_Flow" doc:name="bonanza_addfixedpriceitemSub_Flow"/>
    </flow>
    <sub-flow name="bonanza_addfixedpriceitemSub_Flow">
        <message-properties-transformer doc:name="Message Properties">
            <add-message-property key="X-BONANZLE-API-DEV-NAME" value="t******I"/>
            <add-message-property key="X-BONANZLE-API-CERT-NAME" value="l*****F"/>
        </message-properties-transformer>
        <set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" doc:name="Property"/>
        <set-property propertyName="Accept" value="application/json" doc:name="Property"/>
        <set-variable variableName="sim" value="{requesterCredentials:{bonanzleAuthToken:nWn1a9l3NT}}" doc:name="Variable"/>
        <scripting:transformer returnClass="java.util.Map" doc:name="Groovy">
            <scripting:script engine="Groovy"><![CDATA[import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
m = [addFixedPriceItemRequest:'{requesterCredentials:{bonanzleAuthToken:n*****T}}']
builder = new JsonBuilder()
builder(m)

]]></scripting:script>
        </scripting:transformer>

        <logger message="payload :#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/api_requests/secure_request" method="POST" followRedirects="true" parseResponse="false" doc:name="HTTP">
            <http:success-status-code-validator values="0..599"/>
        </http:request>
        <logger message="resp :#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </sub-flow>
</mule>
```

I am able to receiving successful response from API using postman tool. I try to simulate same thing using above ESB mule flow. But API throws me an error as like below. Hence i have used requestb.in to compare the requests going from esb mule and postman tool. i found differences in the HTTP headers alone.

RAW body from postman to requestb.in -

```
addFixedPriceItemRequest={requesterCredentials:{bonanzleAuthToken:nW*****NT}}
```

RAW Body from ESB mule to requestb.in

```
addFixedPriceItemRequest=%7BrequesterCredentials%3A%7BbonanzleAuthToken%3AnW****NT%7D%7D
```

It seems that i have to serialize the json content before sending as content type - application/x-www-form-urlencoded. I found this info in this [mule doc](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/http-request-connector#HTTPRequestConnector-HTTPRequestBody)

How can i serialize json payload in groovy and sending as map payload?

API Error Response

```
{
  "ack": "Failure",
  "version": "1.0beta",
  "timestamp": "2016-03-15T07:18:11.000Z",
  "errorMessage": {
    "message": "Cannot determine what type of request you are making. Often this can be the result of data that has not been escaped before being passed to the API. If you are passing data with quotation marks or other special characters, you should translate it to JSON, then escape it, before sending it over the API."
  }
}
```

Please let me know for any additional info. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's hard to understand where is the issue you're facing. Is it in sending outbound requests in `http:request` or in forming responses to requests coming in the `http:listener`.

Comment: When you're accepting `gzip` encoding, why are you extracting response payload as String?

Comment: @CharuKhurana Are you mentioning about parsing response in logger node ? i just removed it. Same response.

Comment: @DavidDossot I have updated my query with more information and my find outs. I believe request is going out of Mule when we use gzip,deflate.

Comment: Using a map is not mandatory, the doc explains that **if** you use a map, then the request will be `application/x-form-urlencoded` Your previous String-based approach was good and was producing the right content, as you have confirmed over Postman.

Comment: Also if you want to use the map approach, then just set a map as the body, no need to serialize the map as JSON. If you serialize as a JSON string then you're back to square one. And no need to use Groovy to create the map, just use MEL in `set-payload`

Comment: @DavidDossot Issue is resolved. I have given the solution in below. Thanks for your guidance and continuous support which helped me to keep look into the issue in deeper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flow got worked by adding key value pair in query parms in the http component. The flowVariable requestpayload has json string. So my Mule http component looks like below.

```
<http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/api_requests/secure_request" method="POST" followRedirects="true" parseResponse="false" doc:name="HTTP">
            <http:request-builder>
                <http:query-param paramName="addFixedPriceItemRequest" value="#[flowVars.requestpayload]"/>
            </http:request-builder>
            <http:success-status-code-validator values="0..599"/>
        </http:request>
```